# Python MOTD script doesn't work with degree symbol °

Tags: ssh, python, sshd, python3, motd

I'm using python scripts to create my MOTD in Ubuntu Server 18.04. I found this problem when trying to display the temps of my hard drives. I wanted to display the temperature using the degree symbol as such `##°C`, but the output wouldn't show when I logged in to the server.
Removing the degree symbol fixed the problem.

Example code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

print(u"\u00B0" + "C")
print("°C")
print('°' + "C")
print('\u00B0' + "C")
```

File was saved as `00-testpython`, and running the script from the command line outputs as expected:

```
$ ./00-testpython 
°C
°C
°C
°C
```

Running the scripts with `run-parts` returns the expected response:

```
$ run-parts --lsbsysinit /etc/update-motd.d
°C
°C
°C
°C
```

Logging in with ssh displays whatever was in the old `/run/motd.dynamic`, and does not update with the expected MOTD.

I have a strong feeling that this has something to do with encoding, but I'm not sure what it would be. Printing from python can use ANSI escape characters to print in color; I'm not sure why this is causing an issue.

Using a bash script to echo the degree symbol works fine:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo °
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be an encoding issue as I suspected.
I found a similar question to encoding in the MOTD with the answer I needed here:
https://serverfault.com/a/207357
When I ran the command to check the environment variable `LANG` from my logged-in console, I got the value:

```
$ echo $LANG
C.UTF-8
```

But if I put the same command in my MOTD (bash) script, `LANG` was empty when I logged in. I assume the default would be ASCII in that case, which would have caused issues when encoding the degree symbol.

To fix the problem, in my script I just needed to add the line:

```
export LANG="C.UTF-8"
```

I put this line in a bash script which then calls my python script. I couldn't get it to work in the python script with the command `os.environ['LANG'] = "C.UTF-8"`